# Dip in xml does not work for different screen density in android simulator

Tags: android, dpi, density-independent-pixel

I'm testing multi dpi in android, and the layout xml file seems like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/new_album_bg">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
    <RelativeLayout android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="400dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:background="@drawable/name_text_bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run it on a 480x800 mdpi(160) simulator (scale to 7 inches), it works fine, but on a 480x800 hdpi simulator, it PADDING the EditText down to the near bottom of the screen, nearly 600px, is that 400dip x 240 / 160 ? And It seems has no difference with screen size even I scaled it to 4 inches. How to let padding work under different screen density? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How to let padding work under different screen density?
```

you can create different layout xml with different padding in different folders like

```
res/layout-mdpi 
res/layout-hdpi
```

Then the android will select the appropriate layout xml
**About dp(Dip)**
dp will guarantee that the view is given an appropriate size on the current device screen. For instance, a view with a `layout_width="100dp"` will measure `100 pixels` wide on an `HVGA@160 density` display and `150 pixels` on a `WVGA@240 density` display, but the view will occupy approximately the same physical space.

For more details refer this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: hi Labeeb P, use res/layout-hdpi is ok! thanks! But there're still tiny question: dp was amplified by 1.5, so that the 480x800 240dip screen just perform as 480x800 / 1.5, that is, the screen height is only 533.33 dp that I could use in layout xml, it's not convenient to use. Any suggestions?